# How to get underlying value from a reflect.Value in golang?

Tags: reflection, go

So I found some code that help me get started with reflection in Go (golang), but I'm having trouble getting a the underlying value so that I can basically create a `map[string]string` from a struct and it's fields.

Eventually, I'd like to make the result into a `map[string]interface{}`, but this one issue is kind of blocking me.

The code I have at the moment:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    FirstName string `tag_name:"tag 1"`
    LastName  string `tag_name:"tag 2"`
    Age       int  `tag_name:"tag 3"`
}

func inspect(f interface{}) map[string]string {

    m := make(map[string]string)
    val := reflect.ValueOf(f).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        valueField := val.Field(i)
        typeField := val.Type().Field(i)

        f := valueField.Interface()
        val := reflect.ValueOf(f)
        m[typeField.Name] = val.String()
    }

    return m
}

func dump(m map[string]string) {

    for k, v := range m {
        fmt.Printf("%s : %s\n", k, v)
    }
}

func main() {
    f := &Foo{
        FirstName: "Drew",
        LastName:  "Olson",
        Age:       30,
    }

    a := inspect(f)

    dump(a)
}
```

The output from running the code:

```
FirstName : Drew
LastName : Olson
Age : <int Value>
```

From what I understand the output for FirstName and LastName are actual reflect.Value objects but for strings the String() method on value just outputs the underlying String.  I'd like to either get the int and change it into a string, but from the relfect package documentation I'm not immediately seeing how that's done.

Soo.... How do I get the underlying value from a reflect.Value in golang?

Comment: A printf of a `reflect.Value` will (Go 1.5) print its actual value. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29668838/6309)

Comment: @VonC cool, thanks for your help, managed finally to obtain the value with the help of fmt like you suggested: https://goplay.space/#w98PfGoZHl8

Comment: running solution with field name, type, value and tag: https://goplay.space/#15XAsJBH5Sb

Comment: @Macilias Well done. (And I was not aware of goplay.space, by the way: it looks handy)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A good example of how to parse values is the `fmt` package. See [this code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.20.3/src/fmt/scan.go#L1017-L1053).

Using the mentioned code to match your problem would look like this:

```
switch val.Kind() {
case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
    m[typeField.Name] = strconv.FormatInt(val.Int(), 10)
case reflect.String:
    m[typeField.Name] = val.String()    
// etc...
}
```

Basically you need to check for all [available Kinds](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind).

Comment: Yup -- I was going to post my answer, which is basically the same here.  I think I tried this a number of times, but didn't include the `reflect.Int` type thinking that `reflect.Int32` would cover that.  Once I added that case though things worked better.

Comment: Good that you mention it. The reason for this is that the `Int` type is platform dependant [(but at least 32 bit wide)](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int) where `Int32` and `Int64` have fixed sizes.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're on the right track. The problem I see with your code is it makes assumptions about the values, meaning when do you call `Elem()` and how many times (to resolve pointers). In order to know this you need to look at the `reflect.Kind`. Is the value a `reflect.Ptr`? Then use `Elem()`.

Once you have the value from `val.Interface()` / `val.String()` / `val.Int()`  you can convert your values as needed. What you use is going to depend on `reflect.Kind`. To convert an `int` to/from `string` you need to use the `strconv` package.

The `encoding/json` and `encoding/xml` packages do this kind of work already. The source code provides some great examples. For example, take a look at `copyValue` in [encoding/xml/read.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/xml/read.go) and `marshalSimple` in [encoding/xml/marshal.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go).

Answer (score 6):

This should be easier to do with  Go 1.5 (August 2015) 
See [review 8731](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/8731/) and [commit 049b89d](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/049b89dc6f6b6f1001672dd5456197b74a97cbec) by [Rob Pike (`robpike`)](https://github.com/robpike):

> ### `fmt`: treat `reflect.Value` specially - as the value it holds

This would allow you to print the actual value of a `Reflect.Value()` argument:

> When a `reflect.Value` is passed to `Printf` (etc.), `fmt` called the `String` method, which does not disclose its contents.
>   To get the contents, one could call `Value.Interface()`, but that is illegal
>   if the `Value` is not exported or otherwise forbidden.
>
> This CL improves the situation with a trivial change to the `fmt` package: when we see a `reflect.Value` as an argument, we treat it exactly as we treat a `reflect.Value` we make inside the package.
>   This means that we always print the contents of the `Value` as if *that* was the argument to `Printf`.
>
> This is arguably a breaking change but I think it is a genuine improvement and no greater a break than many other tweaks we have made to formatted output from this package.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution can be ,

```
flavorName = fmt.Sprintf("%v",strct)
```

" *fmt.Sprintf()* " will return the value which can be stored in a variable.