# Dump an array of interfaces in golang

Tags: arrays, go, reflection, dump

I have an array of interfaces like this :

```
type Test struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    result := []Test{
        Test{Name: "ahmad"},
        Test{Name: "reza"},
    }
    dump(result)
}
```

How can I dump this array and make a string like this:

---

Name

ahmad

reza

---

I want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091562/how-to-get-underlying-value-from-a-reflect-value-in-golang) but with arrays.

**Update**

I don't want to dump Test interface...

I want to dump every interfaces.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Test struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    result := []Test{
        Test{Name: "ahmad"},
        Test{Name: "reza"},
    }
    dump(result)
}

func dump(datasets interface{}) {
    items := reflect.ValueOf(datasets)
    if items.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        for i := 0; i < items.Len(); i++ {
            item := items.Index(i)
            if item.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                s := reflect.ValueOf(item)
                t := reflect.TypeOf(item)
                for j := 0; j < s.NumField(); j++ {
                    fmt.Println(t.Field(j).Name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this. But the result is :

```
typ
ptr
flag
typ
ptr
flag
```

How can I change output to :

```
Name
Name
```

Comment: You have an array of `Test` objects, do you really need to treat these items as some interface? In your sample it's certainly not necessary but it's just an example so some clarification would be helpful. If this is truly representative of your code you should 100% be doing `result[i].Name` and not touching reflection or interfaces at all.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal The Test object is just for sample. I don't know what interface will passed to dump function.

Answer (score 0):

Your example could really use more details but here is my best attempt at helping you based off what you've provided. I'm assuming the definition of dump is as follows;

```
 func dump(items []interface{})
```

And that you are specifically looking to print the `Name` field on whatever is passed in, rather than say printing all fields on any object passed in.

```
func dump(items []interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("Name")
    for i := 0; i < len(items); i++ {
          v := reflect.ValueOf(items[i])
          name := v.FieldByName("Name")
          fmt.Println(name.String())
    }
}
```

Working example here; https://play.golang.org/p/zUBt6qkuok

If you instead want to print all fields that can be done with minor changes. Just add another loop inside of this where you iterate on `j < v.NumField()` and use `v.Field(i)` to get each field that's there. There are a lot of ways to structure your code at this level depending on what you want (like if you want to print FieldName1 followed by it's values then FieldName2 followed by it's values ect then your code would look quite different than if you weren't including the headers or printing each field on the current instance one after another). But these are details you'll have to worry about yourself or specify in an update to your question. Some good reading on the topic here; https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection

Also the reflect packages docs are quite helpful.

Comment: Read updated notes on the question. If i know what interface will passed to dump that was very simple. I don't know anything about interface which passes to function.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way !

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Test struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    result := []Test{
        Test{Name: "ahmad"},
        Test{Name: "reza"},
    }
    dump(result)
}

func dump(datasets interface{}) {
    items := reflect.ValueOf(datasets)
    if items.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        for i := 0; i < items.Len(); i++ {
            item := items.Index(i)
            if item.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                v := reflect.Indirect(item)
                for j := 0; j < v.NumField(); j++ {
                    fmt.Println(v.Type().Field(j).Name, v.Field(j).Interface())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/JUAnVoSAwc

Thanks.